# Expand delimited cell in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data structure that looks like this:

```
        A         B                       C
-0.093911  0.597749  foo,bar,delimited,list
-0.460680  0.475724                0.492991
```

I want to split the delimited values in the column out to different rows with the values for the rest of the rows being the same as the target row. Example target dataframe:

```
        A         B          C
-0.093911  0.597749  foo
-0.093911  0.597749  bar
-0.093911  0.597749  delimited
-0.093911  0.597749  list
-0.460680  0.475724  0.492991
```

It's easy to do this with `.iterrows()` and checking for the length of attempting to split the column `'C'` by delimiter, then creating the necessary rows from there. I was wondering if there's a built in I missed in Pandas that can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) working in pandas 0.25+ with [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) column to lists:

```
df = df.assign(C = df.C.str.split(',')).explode('C').reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
          A         B          C
0 -0.093911  0.597749        foo
1 -0.093911  0.597749        bar
2 -0.093911  0.597749  delimited
3 -0.093911  0.597749       list
4 -0.460680  0.475724   0.492991
```